# Гайд-парк чи Гайд-Парк у Лондоні?

Tags: правопис, іншомовні-слова

Стаття на українській [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA) подає "Гайд-парк" (друге слово з малої літери). [Перекладач](https://translate.google.com.ua/?hl=uk&tab=wT#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=uk&text=Hyde%20Park) Google подає "Гайд-Парк" (друге слово з великої літери).

У [правописі](https://pravopys.net/#search=114) (параграф 114) написано:

> в) Географічні назви, що складаються з іншомовних елементів —
> повнозначних слів, а також похідні від них прикметники:
> Буе́нос-А́йрес, Думбарто́н-Окс, Ісси́к-Куль, Кзил-Орда́, Нар’я́н-Мар,
> Рі́о-Не́гро, Ула́н-Уде́; буе́нос-а́йреський та ін., але: Алата́у,
> Амудар’я́, Махачкала́, Сирдар’я́, амудар’ї́нський, приамудар’ї́нський;
> амлмаати́нець, кзилорди́нець та ін.
>
> г) Географічні назви (переважно населених пунктів) з першими складовими
> частинами соль-, спас-, усть- та іншомовними вест-, іст-, нью-, сан-,
> санкт-, сант-, санта-, сен-, сент- і под., а також із кінцевими
> назвотворчими частинами -ривер, -сіті, -сквер, -стрит, -фіорд і
> похідні від них прикметники: Соль-Іле́цьк, Спас-Кле́пики,
> Усть-Каменого́рськ; Вест-І́ндія, Іст-Ло́ндон, Нью-Йо́рк,
> Сан-Сальвадо́р, Санкт-Га́ллен, Сант-Я́го, Са́нта-Кла́ра, Сен-Гота́рд,
> Сент-Луї́с; Фолл-Ри́вер, Атла́нтик-Сі́ті, Са́хо-сквер, Бо́нна-фіо́рд;
> соль-іле́цький, усть-каменого́рський; нью-йо́ркський,
> фолл-ри́верський, атла́нтик-сі́тинський та ін.

Але там нічого не сказано про кінцеву назвотворчу частину "-парк". Заради цікавості подивився, як перекладається Central Park у Нью-Йорку. [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_(%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA)) подає "Центральний парк", без дефісу.

То як правильно перекладати Hyde Park?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [правописі 2015](https://pravopys.net/#search=38) (параграф 38):

> Якщо ж складова частина такої назви увійшла в українську мову як загальна родова назва, то вона пишеться з малої літери: *Вара́нгер-фіо́рд*, *Дю-фіо́рд*. Так само з малої літери пишуться й родові позначення в іншомовних назвах вулиць, майданів, бульварів: *Ка́йзер-плац*, *Лі́бкнехт-штра́се* (штрасе — вулиця), *Трафальга́р-сквер* (сквер — площа), ***Тре́птов-парк***, *Уо́лл-стрит* (стрит — вулиця).

Щоправда з [правопису 2019](https://2019.pravopys.net/sections/50/) (параграф 50) цей приклад прибрали.